# What does "this part only fits if Note: INCLUDING EVOLUTION" refer to?

Tags: civic, heater-blower

I'm searching parts stores for 2012 civic lx blower motor, on amazon each result, in the blue outlined header that says "amazonconfirmedfit (i) This fits 2012 Honda Civic", when clicking the information link (i) states stipulation:

> This product fits only if following criteria are met.

> Position  |   Front

> Note: INCLUDING EVOLUTION

I've searched for EVOLUTION online and here and read the manual. Only online results are from 2012 car reviews. I have no idea what it means. Any ideas?

UPDATE:

The search if for a 2012 Civic blower motor, when asked for details it's an LX with the 1.8l. Also attaching two screenshots. Why does amazon make such huge ugly links?!?

shortened [https://www.amazon.com/dp/B0822NL9RL](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0822NL9RL)

long version [https://www.amazon.com/Youxmoto-Conditioning-2013-2015-2013-2014-79311-TR0-A01/dp/B0822NL9RL/ref=sr_1_3?content-id=amzn1.sym.cb8ad338-1bd3-40db-9a4a-03b37e14bb31%3Aamzn1.sym.cb8ad338-1bd3-40db-9a4a-03b37e14bb31&crid=10ZX07W2CKAIK&keywords=lx+blower+motor&pd_rd_r=a099532d-af74-4b76-9085-56b2049d2c58&pd_rd_w=0B1lT&pd_rd_wg=h1VzE&pf_rd_p=cb8ad338-1bd3-40db-9a4a-03b37e14bb31&pf_rd_r=YRMXJTZTZWK328MXYN0H&pid=fc2zTqK&qid=1706915434&sprefix=2012+civic+lx+blower+motor%2Caps%2C142&sr=1-3&vehicle=2012-59-752-113--1-9-5-16675--1-1---1&vehicleName=2012+Honda+Civic](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0822NL9RL)

[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you add a link to the page where you have seen this comment?

Comment: Don't buy car parts on Amazon, instead go someplace where there's someone who can actually help you. For the extra $1 it might cost, it's well worth the expertise to buy this kind of thing locally.

Comment: I've only bought a few car parts on amazon for more variety that my local stores don't offer or price, but you're probably right and I've just been lucky so far. The local expertise at car parts stores and dealership parts departments (at least what I've found) are a minimum-wage kid who only knows how to search on their website which I can do myself. Just my experience  (albeit limited) buying parts.